# How to copy a cstring to a member variable in a constructors initializer list?

Tags: c++, cstring, initializer-list

Instead of doing it this way:

```
myClass::myClass(char* name) :
    name(nullptr)
{
this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(this->name, name);
}
```

How can I initialize name completely inside of the initializer list?

Comment: Well, you can call a function to create a string copy in the initializer list.... but is there a reason you're not using `std::string`? It essentially does the same thing but with a nicer abstraction.

Comment: My instructor requires cstrings instead of std::string. The other relevant requirement is that all private data members must be initialized inside of the initialization list.

Comment: `My instructor requires cstrings instead of std::string.`  In other words, teaching C instead of C++.  In that case, write your own string class.  It still would meet the requirements, and the syntax would look like you're using `std::string`.

Comment: I don't think it would meet the requirements because the requirement is to use cstrings...

Comment: It would meet the requirement.  Your class would only be using cstrings.  How was std::string developed if it is not based on low-level char arrays and cstrings?  There are many home-made string classes that mimic std::string that, yes, are inferior to std::string, but at least gives you something to work with that makes things easier when you get your next assignment that requires you to "only use cstrings".

Comment: Since your instructor is a cstring-toting neanderthal anyway, you could always POSIX it up and use `strdup()`, then `free()` in the destructor. And if you can't use POSIX, then write your own. yes, it is hideous and has no place in a modern C++ program, but so too is the assignment.

Answer (score 4):

Since we're dealing with exercises in futility:

```
myClass::myClass(char* name): name_{
  [](char* n) {
    auto ret = new char[strlen(n) + 1]; 
    strcpy(ret, n);
    return ret;
  }(name)
} {}
```

Comment: Now *that* fufills the requirements!

Comment: For most embedded systems, I'd also expect to see an absolute maximum buffer size here, and usage of strnlen (note the N) and strncpy (note the N), using your YADDA_MAXBUF value as a safety.

Comment: Also, this is an answer that demonstrates significant language proficiency, but nonetheless makes me wince a little bit.  The average person reading or maintaining that code is going to wonder what in the hell is going on.

So I'd like to point out that the goal of ALL of these things-- the changes to the language standards, initializer lists in general, etc.-- is to reduce danger.  And code like this does not reduce danger.  It increases the danger someone is going to misunderstand it.  Which its author clearly knows, hence his comment. =]

Answer (score 0):

The following may be interesting to you.  I wondered what the Joint Strike Fighter (JSF) Air Vehicle C++ Coding Standards document had to say about this, so I checked:

**(UNCLASS)**

> "**AV Rule 74:**
>
> Initialization of nonstatic class members will be performed through
> the member initialization list rather than through assignment in the
> body of a constructor. See Meyers [6], item 12.
>
> **Exception:**
>
> Assignment should be used when an initial value cannot be represented by a
> simple expression (e.g. **initialization of array values**), or when a name must
> be introduced before it can be initialized (e.g. value received via an
> input stream).
>
> See AV Rule 74 in Appendix A for details."

**(/UNCLASS)**

Now, the JSF spec is a product of its time-- circa 2005, for the revision I looked at-- but prior to the newer C++ language variants, this was the best thinking on the matter.  (The Meyers reference in question is "Effective C++", for example.)

While the newer language standards provide more options, it can be kind of infuriating getting people who really know those specs to listen to you when you ask how they apply to non-"std::*" types, and more often than not you're talking about C-style, null-terminated strings.  Their response tends to be, "don't do that".

Unfortunately, in the embedded systems world and a number of other places, std::array, std::string, etc., still suffer from significant to severe performance problems with any number of vendor-specific toolchains, and occasionally having no choice but to attempt to find a compromise that uses modern C++ best practices on older C data types is something that, as of 2022, absolutely still occurs.

For my own C-string uses cases, I typically use the initializer list to zero the entire target array, and then strncpy (note the N!) in the function body.  This is because I often have to go to a little extra trouble to make sure all the memory I'm using is thoroughly scrubbed.

(I'll also mention that if you REALLY have to make sure of that, there are replacement memory management libraries that are truly paranoid about it, but you can pay a pretty significant performance penalty, so it's better to learn how to get what you want from your code in the first place.  They can, however, sometimes be a decent solution to help shore up ancient codebases you don't have time to retrofit.)